# How can I create an universal function from this code and how can I call it via "onclick" button action

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four `<button>`, Each one has a specific id (`b1`, `b2`, `b3`, `b4`) and when clicking on it, It would take me to a specific `<div>` that has an id (`marina1`, `marina2`, `ecc`...). Is there a way to not write four times this function (one function for one specific button)?

Like creating an universal one with two parameters as input (But I don't know how to pass those two parameters to the function)?

**This is the code:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $("#b1").click(function (){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#marina1").offset().top
            }, 2000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: show your html too,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there a another you can do it. You can add a common class to all the id elements. Just give it a try .

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .click {
      cursor: pointer
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <span class="click" id="1">1</span><br>
  <span class="click" id="2">2</span><br>
  <span class="click" id="3">3</span><br>
  <span class="click" id="4">4</span>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".click").on('click', function() {
        var id = this.id;
        alert(id);
        // code to be executed
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

To achieve this you can first use common classes on the buttons and divs to group them. Then you can use `data` attributes to store the relative information on the `button` elements which you can read in the click handler to `toggle()` the relevant `div`. Try this:

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $($(this).data('target')).toggle();
});
```

```css
.marina {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" id="b1" data-target="#marina1">Marina 1</button>
<button class="btn" id="b2" data-target="#marina2">Marina 2</button>
<button class="btn" id="b3" data-target="#marina3">Marina 3</button>

<div class="marina" id="marina1">Marina 1 details...</div>
<div class="marina" id="marina2">Marina 2 details...</div>
<div class="marina" id="marina3">Marina 3 details...</div>
```

FYI this technique is known as 'Don't Repeat Yourself', or DRY.